# Calculating the MOSFET gate resistor for an H-bridge driver

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I'm designing a DC motor driver using Allegro's [A3941K](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/brush-dc-motor-drivers/a3941) driver. The block schematic shows a gate resistor for the MOSFETs. The A3941 gate structures are as below,

[image: Input and Output Structures]

The `GHx` voltage would be a maximum of 18V? Knowing the current that should flow into the gate would help me calculate the value of the resistance. I found this app note from Microchip on [Driving Power MOSFETs in High-Current, Switch Mode Regulators](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00786a.pdf). Using the equations from there and the data from the MOSFET [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSC100N06LS3-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ddc9372011ebb0823387fd7), I calculate the Ig = Qg/t(rise time) = 10nC/58nS = ~172mA. Hence, the gate resistor Rg = 18/172mA = ~105ohms. Is this the correct line of thinking?

The switching frequency is 20KHz and the MOSFET used is [BSC100N06LS3](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSC100N06LS3-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ddc9372011ebb0823387fd7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on [another forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/k5odan/calculating_the_mosfet_gate_resistor_for_an/gegamp7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

I had misread the total gate charge as 10nC. In reality, it is 45nC. The `Gxx` is also 15V (Sx+15V from the motor driver's datasheet). Hence the required `Ig` to turn on the MOSFET is 45nC/58nS = ~776mA. Hence `Rg = 15V/776mA = 19.3ohms`. However, as pointed in the answer on the other forum, rise time need not be that high. Hence assuming the rise time to be 1% of the switching frequency, we get `t(transition)` to be 500nS. Recalculating for Ig,

`Ig = 45nC/500nS = 90mA, and, Rg = 15V/90mA = ~167ohms`

Comment: You, and the other site, still miss that gate driver is working against gate Miller voltage,  not zero. So wherever you write 15V you should have 15V-4V=11V instead